# simple jquery string count not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code below...

```
var mymonth=new Date().getMonth();
console.log((mymonth).length);
```

I am getting an error `undefined` in console.. i have already tried..

```
console.log((new Date().getMonth()).length);
```

but still the same error...Iam supposed to get the length of month `1` whats the issue with this???

Comment: `mymonth` is a numerical value which does not have the length property.. so try `console.log((''+ mymonth).length);`

Comment: Try, `console.log((mymonth.toString()).length);`

Comment: you could have first checked what console.log(new Date().getMonth()); outputs before trying to check for length

Comment: You'll need to convert the value to a string before you use the length property.

Comment: or use the `<` operator like `mymonth < 10`

Comment: What are you tryint to do? Roughly 80% of the time the month will have one digit (0 to 9), 20% of the time it will have two (10 or 11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mymonth` is a numerical value which does not have the length property, so try

```
var mymonth=new Date().getMonth();
console.log((''+ mymonth).length);
```

or use a numerical comparison like below to check whether the month is of 2 digits or not

```
mymonth < 10
```

Comment: @sudharsan Clearly not **always**

Answer (score 0):

It is in date format so you convert to string first and count the length.Use `.toString()` in javascript

```
var mymonth=new Date().getMonth();
console.log(mymonth.toString().length);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8cpy/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date value to string and then count the length. Try this:

```
var mymonth=new Date().getMonth();
console.log(mymonth.toString().length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var mymonth=new Date().getMonth();
alert((mymonth).toString().length);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getMonth` returns `int` value and it does not have `length` property. You need to make it string first and then call `length`.

```
var mymonth=new Date().getMonth();
console.log(mymonth.toString().length);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to parse the date/month  to string coz by default it gives an integer value and length property only work with string , object or array types !**

```
var mymonth=String(new Date().getMonth());
console.log(mymonth.length);

will give you 1 as a o/p
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/5kTqk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The .length operator doesn't return the number of days in the month, that is more for arrays and strings.

What you need is to take advantage of the Date object constructor!

```
function getDaysInMonth(year, day) {
    return new Date(year, day, 0).getDate();
}
```

Just pass in your date object before console.log, like this

```
console.log( getDaysInMonth( Date().getYear(), mymonth) );
```